# Errors with ES2015 transpiling; static proptypes, display names; configuring webpack, babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, production-environment, babeljs

JS newb here:

I've spent a couple days on this bug, and I've looked at many answers and practiced my most earnest Google-Fu, and tried many different babel plugins and presets configurations, as well as tried migrating my webpack 1 project into a webpack 2 incarnation, and in the end I'm still hitting the same wall. Please give me an assist.

When I try to build my project, all open sourced [here](https://github.com/sgoldens/home/tree/webpack2migration), and most recently active and relevant to this question in the webpack2migration branch, I've been unable to build for production (and not even dev after futzing more and more with it through unproductive debugging)

This is the error I haven't gotten around, admittedly because I don't understand some (maybe many) of the complexities in webpack and how babel is to be correctly configured for what I'm struggling with.

Here's the **error**:

```
ERROR in ../~/react-google-maps/src/lib/async/withScriptjs.js
Module parse failed: /Users/sg/Desktop/blog-home/node_modules/react-google-maps/src/lib/async/withScriptjs.js Unexpected token (19:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default function withScriptjs(WrappedComponent) {
|   return class Container extends Component {
|     static displayName = `withScriptjs(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;
|
|  static propTypes = {
```

Initially, I thought this was a bug with [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps), but I suspect it is something different now. I have encountered this kind of bug once before a few months ago within a different project, and I know I've been mostly making a mess of my package.json.

Yes, I know there are many silly problems in there, like package duplications, unused packages, unnecessary dependencies... I've been hitting every angle I can think of, too hard and with not enough care towards cleanup yet; I'm asking for help before getting some sleep and trying yet again in the morning.

The project was to integrate a working [small frontend game](http://geo-quiz.herokuapp.com/) I'm prototyping, and I wanted to integrate it into my homepage, which I'm also beginning another sweep to clean up and refactor, for better presentation and code quality.

I humbly ask for some supportive help in configuring my build correctly where I obviously am having a lot of trouble.

When I began to integrate the little game into my home page, the build worked perfectly on my local machine in both development and production build configurations, but when I pushed my changes and triggered a build to my heroku host site it kept failing on this same file, I suppose because it can't parse it.

[image]

I hope that is enough to go on, and I'll be happy to help narrow this down as needed. :)

Best regards, and thanks for your time!

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-sg-home-page",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "description": "My home page and portfolio site",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/sgoldens/home.git"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "mock-local-storage"
  },
  "config": {
    "blanket": {
      "pattern": [
        ""
      ],
      "data-cover-never": [
        "node_modules",
        "__tests__",
        "*.spec.*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "buildcolors": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
    "start_nf": "nf start",
    "istanbul": "istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --reporter dot --full-trace __tests__",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "mochatest": "babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/isparta cover _mocha --require blanket -- --reporter dot --full-trace __tests__",
    "postinstall": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.js",
    "remove-public": "rm -rf ./public",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "start_prod": "node server.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dashboard -t 'Marvin' -- webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
    "lint-break-on-errors": "eslint ./source/js ./webpack.config.js -f table --ext .js --ext .jsx",
    "lint": "eslint ./source/js ./webpack.config.js -f table --ext .js --ext .jsx || true",
    "preview": "rm -rf ./build && NODE_ENV=\"production\" webpack-dashboard -t 'Preview Mode - Marvin' -- webpack-dev-server",
    "hook-add": "prepush install",
    "hook-remove": "prepush remove",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm run remove-public && mkdir public",
    "heroku-postinstall": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "Sasha Goldenson",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "enzyme": "2.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.10.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.7.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.11",
    "expect": "^1.19.0",
    "factory-girl": "^4.2.2",
    "isparta": "^4.0.0",
    "istanbul": "^1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.1",
    "jest": "17.0.3",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "mocha": "3.1.2",
    "mocha-lcov-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "mock-local-storage": "^1.0.2",
    "nock": "^8.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "standard": "^10.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-es6-polyfill": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-class-display-name": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-display-name": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-babili": "0.0.12",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-modern-async": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "babel-preset-modern-browsers": "^9.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-relay-plugin-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "0.0.11",
    "blanket": "^1.2.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "cheerio": "^0.20.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.1",
    "coveralls": "^2.12.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "es6-promise": "^3.3.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "express": "~4.9.8",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "foreman": "2.0.0",
    "get-env": "^0.5.10",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.2.2",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.2",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.0-rc2",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^1.8.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "prepush": "^3.1.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-display-name": "^0.2.0",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-google-maps": "^7.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.5",
    "react-lazy-cache": "^3.0.1",
    "react-logo": "^1.0.8",
    "react-modal": "1.5.2",
    "react-mui-speeddial": "0.0.6",
    "react-pure-render": "^1.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
    "react-router-dom": "next",
    "react-rte": "^0.11.0",
    "react-rte-image": "^0.11.1",
    "react-rte-material": "^0.12.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "*",
    "react-tooltip": "3.2.2",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.4",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.2.0",
    "redux-form": "6.6.1",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "^4.1.3",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.3",
    "reinstall": "^1.1.1",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.6",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "svgo": "^0.7.2",
    "svgo-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "transform-runtime": "0.0.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.10.0",
    "youtube-api-search": "0.0.5"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sgoldens/home/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sgoldens/home#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "home"
  ],
  "prepush": [
    "npm run lint-break-on-errors --silent"
  ]
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }],
    "transform-class-display-name",
    "class-display-name",
    "transform-react-display-name",
    "syntax-decorators",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    ["transform-es2015-template-literals", {
        "loose": true,
        "spec": true
      }]
  ],
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const SpritePlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProduction = nodeEnv === 'production';

const jsSourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './src');
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, './build');
const imgPath = path.join(__dirname, './images');
const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, './images');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './src');


// Common plugins
const plugins = [
  new SpritePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'build',
    filename: 'build.js',
    minChunks(module) {
      const context = module.context;
      return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
    },
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv),
      'API_HOST': JSON.stringify('https://posts-sgoldens.herokuapp.com'),
      'API_PORT': JSON.stringify(process.env.PORT || 5000)
    },
  }),
  new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(sourcePath, 'index.html'),
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'index.html',
  }),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: [
            'last 3 version',
            'ie >= 10',
          ],
        }),
      ],
      context: sourcePath,
    },
  }),
];

// Common rules
const rules = [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      'babel-loader',
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        options: {
          extract: true,
          spriteFilename: 'icons-sprite.svg',
        },
      },
      'svgo-loader',
    ],
    include: iconPath,
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/,
    include: imgPath,
    use: 'url-loader?limit=20480&name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
  },
];

if (isProduction) {
  // Production plugins
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style-[hash].css')
  );

  // Production rules
  rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
      }),
    }
  );
} else {
  // Development plugins
  plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin()
  );

  // Development rules
  rules.push(
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        // Using source maps breaks urls in the CSS loader
        // https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/232
        // This comment solves it, but breaks testing from a local network
        // https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/232#issuecomment-240449998
        // 'css-loader?sourceMap',
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader?sourceMap',
      ],
    }
  );
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProduction ? false : 'source-map',
  context: jsSourcePath,
  entry: {
    js: './index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: buildPath,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack-loader.js', '.web-loader.js', '.loader.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      jsSourcePath,
    ],
  },
  plugins,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: isProduction ? buildPath : sourcePath,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
    compress: isProduction,
    inline: !isProduction,
    hot: !isProduction,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    stats: {
      assets: true,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      hash: false,
      modules: false,
      publicPath: false,
      timings: true,
      version: false,
      warnings: true,
      colors: {
        green: '\u001b[32m',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is importing separate **source** file from node_modules folder `react-google-maps/*src*/lib/async/withScriptjs.js`

But your webpack rules exclude files in node_modules from babel compilation process

```
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/, // NB!
    use: [
      'babel-loader',
    ],
  }
```

You could import compiled version instead `/react-google-maps/**lib**/async/withScriptjs.js`

Comment: Thanks, @Yury, I appreciate the knowledge for future projects. I actually decided to use this opportunity to migrate my code to a more stable and supported boilerplate, create-react-app, which didn't share this problem.